# How to encapsulate JSON in parentheses?

Tags: python, django, json, eval, simplejson

I have this code :

```
objects = Event.objects.all()
i = 0
dict = {}
small_dict = {}
for o in objects:
    small_dict = {'id': o.id, 'url': o.url, 'name': o.name, 'image': o.image}
    dict[str(i+1)] = small_dict
    small_dict = {}

return HttpResponse(
    simplejson.dumps(dict),
    content_type = 'application/javascript; charset=utf8'
)
```

and it gives me this :

```
{"1": {"url": "http://www.rte.ie/tv/crimecall/", "image": "http://img.rasset.ie/0002c8d0-250.jpg", "id": 2, "name": "Crimecall"}}
```

How I can further encapsulate it between `()` parentheses ? Because without them I'm getting error when parsing them in php.

Comment: `"(" + simplejson.dumps(dict) + ")"`?  Or what exactly is your goal?

Comment: What you get is valid JSON output.  Maybe you shoould fix the PHP code.

Comment: I'm getting ' invalid label' error and from what I was able to find, adding parentheses fixes the problem

Comment: You didn't even say what PHP code you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way, but it's not viewable in browser now. I'f that's not a problem, here's the code :

```
callback = request.GET.get('callback', '')
objects = Event.objects.all()
i = 0
dict = {}
small_dict = {}
for o in objects:
    small_dict = {'id': o.id, 'url': o.url, 'name': o.name, 'image': o.image}
    dict[str(i+1)] = small_dict
    small_dict = {}

response = simplejson.dumps(dict)
response = callback + '(' + response + ')';

return HttpResponse(response,
    mimetype ='application/json; charset=utf8')
```

Comment: brilliant it works ! And I've already downloaded some dumb django-rest-api :)

Answer (score 2):

1. The MIME type of JSON is "application/json".
2. If you have problems parsing it in *PHP*, then it's a *PHP* problem. Don't add parens on the server side, but rather add them before parsing the string in PHP. I guess you know how to concatenate in PHP, right? Anyway, I don't understand what your problem is - don't you use [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?